# WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an XWayland server

Tags: debian, xorg, wayland

System - Debian 12

Console is showing following error:
WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an XWayland server
WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an XWayland server

I am expecting no warning like this

Comment: Is this question about programming? Else you are in the wrong site. You may get better answer on more relevant sites (e.g. check our sister sites on top right icon). And it is just a warning: if you are not packaging programs or if you do not have real errors, just ignore it. If you think it is a real bug in Debian, fill a bug in BTS.